# Comparing two percentages, that regard to data A(first percentage) that is subset of data B (second percentage)

Tags: analysis, statistics, number-comparison

I want to compare two percentages to see how much they differ one from another. For example: 
I have 1000 products - 100 of them are on promotion. (10% products on promotion)
The total products are divided into 3 subsets:

- Small products, (500)
- Medium products, (300)
- Large products. (200)

If I want to look at the large products (200) and 50 of them are on promotion at the moment. This gives us 25% of the Large products are on promotion at the moment.

What I want to do is to compare this two % in a way to show me how much they differ one from another. I don't think to subtract one from the another is a good way of doing this. I was looking at different statistical tests but I was not sure what I should use. How should I approach this (I will compare all subsets to the total individually)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not sure how elementary this question is. There are 2.5 (=250%=$\frac{25%}{10%}$) times more Large Products on Promotion, than the 10% expected from the total. This means that only 50 of the 800 Small and Medium products are on promotion, as opposed to the 80 expected from the 10% figure. Thus these categories are under-represented by $\frac{5}{8}$ = 62.5%.

Comment: @RoySimpson, Yes this is correct. I am looking at various data and this is an example. I can have for example 1 Large product that is on promotion, giving me 100% products on promotion. I want to try to compare them having in mind the size of products the percentage represents. This is why I am not sure what is the best way to compare the % products on promotion for a subset to the % total products on promotion. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Would it be possible to express this problem more algebraically? For example: there are three categories L,M,S, L+M+S =T (total). P% of T is on promotion, and LP% of L is on Promotion, and you want to know what percentage of M+S is on promotion? Then the answer can be more generic too, for categories, and arbitrary percentages and quantities.

Comment: @RoySimpson all I want to do is to compare one of the categories (L on promotion) to the total products on promotion and get a coefficient or a percentage of this difference that makes mathematical sense. When doing this I don't care about the rest of the categories. I already know how many of the products for each category are on promotion and this is why I will run the same test/calculation for each category individually. I was thinking of a test, for example, the two-sample t-test for subgroups from a single sample. But I am not sure which one to use because there are so many.